# BizTalk 2020 Deprecating WCF-BasicHttp

Tags: java, wcf, biztalk, powershell-4.0, biztalk-2020

I just saw on this [Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/install-and-config-guides/whats-new-in-biztalk-server-2020#deprecated--removed-list) that that WCF-BasicHTTP adapter is being deprecated in BizTalk 2020.

In the past, I thought this was used for programs like Java to be able to call orchestrations published as WebServices in BizTalk.  Has Java added full WCF compliance now, which seems strange as WCF is a Microsoft technology (but I know it implements many of the WS2 features). Or the other way around, does WSHttp support Java calls?

What about Microsoft PowerShell calling a published orchestration in BizTalk.  I was able to get it to work with WCF-BasicHTTP and then quit because it was working.  Does it support WCF-WSHttp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what that page says is that the are deprecating the SOAP adapter and that the replacement for it is the WCF-BasicHTTP adapter

What is deprecated is the WCF-NetTcpRelay adapter